# A better way to make matrix - log operations in Eigen?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am playing around with Eigen doing some calculations with matrices and logs/exp, but I found the expressions I got a bit clumsy (and also possibly slower?). Is there a better way to write calculations like this ?

```
MatrixXd m = MatrixXd::Random(3,3);
m = m * (m.array().log()).matrix();
```

That is, not having to convert to arrays, then back to a matrix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are mixing array and matrix operations you can't really avoid them, except for some functions which have a `cwise` function which works directly on matrices (e.g., `cwiseSqrt()`, `cwiseAbs()`).

However, neither `.array()` nor `.matrix()` will have an impact on runtime when compiled with optimization (on any reasonable compiler).
If you consider that more readable, you can work with [`unaryExpr()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a3929764ba38ac4eeca46274a0bf3a7b3).

Comment: Its not that i want to use arrays, i just need to easily be able to run operations on all induvidual elements, and also use matrix operations :)

Thank you for letting me know about the runtime tho :) perhaps i can make it a bit cleaner by making a few macros :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree fully with [chtz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846459/2899559), and reiterate that there is no runtime cost to the "casts." You can confirm using the following toy program:

```
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    typedef MatrixXd matType;
    //typedef MatrixXf matType;
    volatile int vN = 1024 * 4;
    int N = vN;
    auto startAlloc = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    matType m  = matType::Random(N, N).array().abs();
    matType r1 = matType::Zero(N, N);
    matType r2 = matType::Zero(N, N);
    auto finishAlloc = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    r1 = m * (m.array().log()).matrix();
    auto finishLog = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    r2 = m * m.unaryExpr<float(*)(float)>(&std::log);
    auto finishUnary = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::cout << (r1 - r2).array().abs().maxCoeff() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Allocation\t" <<   std::chrono::duration<double>(finishAlloc - startAlloc).count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Log\t\t" <<        std::chrono::duration<double>(finishLog - finishAlloc).count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "unaryExpr\t" <<    std::chrono::duration<double>(finishUnary - finishLog).count() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

On my computer, there is a slight advantage (~4%) to the first form which probably has to do with the way that the memory is loaded (unchecked). Beyond that, the reason for "casting" the type is to remove any ambiguities. For a clear example, consider `operator *`. In the matrix form, it should be considered matrix multiplication, whereas in the array form, it should be coefficient wise multiplication. The ambiguity in the case of `exp` and `log` are the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) and [matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix) respectively. Presumably, you want the element wise `exp` and `log` and therefore the cast is necessary.