# Problem with Eigen natural log function: "implicit instantiation of undefined template"

Tags: c++, math, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I am working on a chemistry simulation that uses Eigen for calculations involving linear algebra.

Here is my code for determining gibbs free energy yield given a current vector of substrate concentrations:

```
#define R 8.314   // Gas constant - J mol^-1 K^-1
#define T 298.0   // Temperature - K

typedef Eigen::MatrixXf Matrix;
typedef Eigen::VectorXf Vector;

Vector calculateGibbs(Vector C, Matrix S, Vector F) {
    /** Calculate value of G vector based on current
        concentration vector C, stoichiometric matrix S, temperature T,
        and standard ∆G˚ vector F.

            Formula Used: G = S^t * (F + RT ln C)

        Where R is the universal gas constant (see line 16),
        and S^t is the transpose of S.
    */
    double RT = R * T;
    return S.transpose() * (F + RT * C.log());
}
```

When I try to compile code that calls this function, I get the following error:

```
error: implicit instantiation of
      undefined template 'Eigen::MatrixLogarithmReturnValue<Eigen::Matrix<float,
      -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >'
    return S.transpose() * (F + RT * C.log());
                                       ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h:287:34: note: 
      template is declared here
template<typename Derived> class MatrixLogarithmReturnValue
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the documentation for the natural logarithm function I am referencing: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html.

Can anyone clarify what I'm doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** To be clear, my goal is to figure out how to take the natural log of a vector using the Eigen framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of Eigen's coefficient-wise operations, including `.log()`,  [refer to Array objects](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html). The coefficient-wise log operation cannot be applied to the `Matrix` type used in your example (or to the `Vector` typedef, which is just a special case of `Matrix`).

Using `.array()` and `.matrix()` makes it possible to switch between the types. In your case the returned value could be:

```
return S.transpose() * (F.array() + RT * C.array().log()).matrix();
```

or, equivalently,

```
return S.transpose() * (F + RT * C.array().log().matrix());
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Its a little confusing to me why they do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution!

[A better way to make matrix - log operations in Eigen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845200/a-better-way-to-make-matrix-log-operations-in-eigen)

I needed to convert the C vector to an array, call the log method, then convert it back to a matrix! Vector addition still worked in the end since in Eigen vectors are a subclass of a matrix (unlike numpy, which differentiates between N-dimensional arrays and 1xN dimensional arrays).